# Help me to find a specific category of typefaces

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation

I'm looking for a serif typeface whose curvy letters (c, s, e etc) have thick/wide spine and instead of the serif, a properly rounded ear (like on some lowercase a, c). Kind of like Didone or ITC Bodoni 72 but the links between the ear and the spine are not that thin. . And to find lowercase 's' with such ear is a difficulty itself.

[image: Drawing is pretty bad but you get the idea.]

Drawing is pretty bad but you get the idea.

Can you name few of such category? Free and paid both? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

These fonts are a modern Roman from the 19th century with a thick stroke made to use it as a display font. Commercially they are called **Fat Face**.

You can look for "Fat Face" fonts like:

[Poster](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/textaxis/poster/) from myfonts.con

[image]

[Fat Face](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/fat-face/)

[image]

[Reina](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/argentina-lian-types/reina/)

[image]

And a classic **Bodoni Poster**

[image]

Pistilli Roman designed by [Herbert Lubalin](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herb_Lubalin)

[image]

Comment: Yes and I just found out they don't work very well in small scale. Asking to confirm, they were not made for small-scale right?

Comment: I don't think so, is a display font.

Comment: I was reading Google's material doc and it advises against the use of script and display fonts as screen font because the scaling in a thing. Anyways, I was experimenting with some of those display fonts, aka fatface  and for the thin complementary strokes, I found they reduce readability at small scale almost 80% of the time when compared to sans-serifs or slab-serif.
I found a typeface called Vidaloka which has very balanced thin and thick strokes. Although it still loses readability in small size when compared to Roboto or Helvetica.